# codeigniter form, no action when submited

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a codeigniter form, but when I press the button nothing happen.
I've already checked everything a thousand time but nothing happen.

Here is the form code:

```
    $this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->helper('captcha');

$attributs = array('class' => 'col-md-12 col-xs-12', 'id' => 'inscription');
echo form_open('utilisateur/ajouter', $attributs);
echo "Nom <br>".form_input('nom','test')."<br>";
echo "Prénom <br>".form_input('prenom','test')."<br>";
echo "Age <br>".form_input('age','test')."<br>";
echo "Pseudo <br>".form_input('pseudo','test')."<br>";
echo "Email <br>".form_input('email','test')."<br>";
echo "Mot de passe <br>".form_password('mdp','test')."<br>";
echo "Confirmation <br>".form_password('mdpConf','test')."<br>";
$bouton = array(
    'name' => 'button',
    'class' => 'button',
    'content' => 'Valider !'
);
echo "<br>".form_button($bouton);
echo form_close();
```

And the controller called code:

```
    class Utilisateur extends CI_Controller {
    protected $Pseudo;
    protected $Email;
    protected $Nom;
    protected $Prenom;
    protected $Age;
    protected $DateInscription;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Pseudo=$Pseudo;
        $this->Email=$Email;
        $this->Nom=$Nom;
        $this->Prenom=$Prenom;
        $this->Age=$Age;
        $this->DateInscription=$DateInscription;
    }
    public function ajouter()
    {
        redirect('pages/view/accueil/', 'location');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more detail about your desired behavior?  Also, how can you tell nothing is happening?

Comment: Your button does now have any `type => "submit"`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `codeignitor` for quite some time, but surely if you want to submit the form you should be using `form_submit($bouton);` rather than `form_button($bouton);`

Answer (score 0):

use `form_submit()`,

```
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');
```

Would produce:

```
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Post!" />
```

In your case,

```
form_submit($bouton);
```

would produce

```
<input type="submit" content="Valider !" class="button" value="" name="button">
```

**Is Anything missing??**

Answer is yes.

**What?**

Value to submit button.

```
$bouton = array(
    'name' => 'button',
    'class' => 'button',
    'content' => 'Valider !',//this will work for button, not submit button.
    'value' => 'Valider !'     

);
```

For more reference, see [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: Ok thanks it's working with form_submit, and even with the value added to the submit button it doesn't work.

Comment: Without value what are you getting as value??

Comment: I ment form_button not submit button, it never work apparently, so nothing. Anyway it's working with form_submit so who cares, thanks :)

Comment: for normal button, `content` will work, but for `submit` button, it will not work.